# Is there any API to directly send messages to Instagram

Tags: python

I am trying to send a message in Instagram via selenium. Is there any API available for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official API for this. But there is some open source work available that can be used. Although they are also using selenium internally.
Here are some of them.

https://github.com/CamTosh/instagram-bot-dm
https://gist.github.com/baptx/99f3cb6373d4a8cf869c25f0549b0c5c

Please try to play around with these.